# How to pass the http header in graphql request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a graphql request in jmeter i need to pass http headers three values device platform, device version and authorization. I will attach the screenshot below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh6Zs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the HTTP Request > Add > Config Element > HTTP Header Manager.

In the HTTP Header Manager, you can add as many headers as you need. For instance, if you need to pass an authorization token, you can add a header named Authorization with a value like Bearer your_token_here.

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you can add [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) via special element called [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

So if you add it as a child of a single GraphQL HTTP Request sampler - it will add the defined headers to only this sampler:

[image]

If you move it to the same level as several GraphQL HTTP Request Samplers - the headers will be applied to all of them

More information:

- [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- [Using JMeter's HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)